# Facebook Comments box redirects to some weird URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

Ok, I've integrated the comments box into my website, and here's is a page from my test site, where you can see the comments box on the bottom:

http://test.canp.co/programming/5/working-with-xaml

There's no problem with this. I've posted a test comment, and I can see it in my Facebook profile. When I click the link to the page from Facebook, it has appended some IDs to use it within its own system, here's the URL when I click from Facebook:

http://test.canp.co/programming/5/working-with-xaml?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150349734853770_19900263_10150349735753770#f2af0d70b1e6c8

However, when I click this link, it opens the page, scrolls to the bottom to the comment, and when the page loads fully, it redirects me to some random nonsense URL, such as `http://test.canp.co/2af0d70b1e6c8`. That random part changes every time, and, obviously, I'm getting a 404 error.

What could be causing this? A bug within the Facebook comments box itself, or did I do somwething wrong? What should I be doing? I want the comments box in my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the following in contentpage.js on your site:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (location.hash.length > 2) {
        location.replace("/" + location.hash.substring(2));
        return;
    }
```

Notice the #f2af0d70b1e6c8 at the end of the URL that facebook hits, and the fact that you get redirected to /2af0d70b1e6c8.....

Given that you're taking location.hash.substring(2) instead of .substring(1), I assume you're looking for #! or #/ followed by whatever resource the user wants.  You should explicitly check for those exact formats instead of any old hash.

Comment: oh, never thought that would be the case, but it is obvious as I see now :) i'll be correcting it. thank you, or i'll be scratching my head and thinking it was maybe a facebook bug :)